# Error : increase sysctl fs.aio-max-nr while configuring SQL Server in Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu-20.04

I have successfully installed SQL Server in Ubuntu 20.04.5. But while configuring SQL Server running the command `/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup` and answering to all questions, I got the following error

```
    The following diagnostic information is available:

         Reason: 0x00000003
         Status: 0x0000000b
        Message: Unable to create a new asynchronous I/O context. Please increase sysctl fs.aio-max-nr
          Stack:
                 IP               Function
                 ---------------- --------------------------------------
                 0000555a422995b2 <unknown>
                 0000555a42298fd0 <unknown>
                 0000555a422032af <unknown>
                 0000555a422b1d11 <unknown>
                 0000555a422b1af8 <unknown>
                 0000555a42253096 <unknown>
                 0000555a4225386e <unknown>
                 0000555a422bf0ca <unknown>
                 0000555a421fa8ad <unknown>
                 00007f7ed3521083 __libc_start_main+0xf3
                 0000555a421fa77e <unknown>
        Process: 13543 - sqlservr
         Thread: 13543
    Instance Id: e13b426f-6907-4503-b340-4d6575d62a76
       Crash Id: 48813d78-4d11-482e-8318-bbd3b504e5ab
    Build stamp: d81e9b6de06534e649bd57dd609aa3050f5e380f361b7f8a80a80eeb71e7422c
Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
     Processors: 2
   Total Memory: 270359584768 bytes
      Timestamp: Tue Dec  6 03:58:53 2022
     Last errno: 11
Last errno text: Resource temporarily unavailable
Capturing a dump of 13543
sqlservr: utils.cpp:561: uintptr_t GetEndOfLibOSVmRange(): Assertion `GetGlobals()->GetStatics()->IsLibOSVmmRangeEndValid()' failed.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: So if you run `sysctl fs.aio-max-nr` what's the current result?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning . it's fs.aio-max-nr = 65536

Comment: Microsoft doesn't have much advice for setting it, except in the context of [Big Data Clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/performance-guidelines-tuned?view=sql-server-ver15). You could try increasing it, but not as high as 1048576 unless you have a massive I/O subsystem.

Comment: I'm not able to change this the value ```fs.aio-max-nr```, I have tried to modify in the file ```/etc/sysctl.conf``` but ```sysctl fs.aio-max-nr``` continue to show fs.aio-max-nr = 65536.
Any thoughts

Comment: Normally you'd `sudo sysctl fs.aio-max-nr=someNewNumber`, it might also need a restart to take effect.

Comment: It says ```sysctl: setting key "fs.aio-max-nr", ignoring: Read-only file system```

Comment: @Bentech where you able to find a solution to this problem? I can not even get `sysctl fs.aio-max-nr` to run. The system tells me `sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr: No such file or directory`.

Comment: No I was not able to solve it, My web-hoster told me that this configuration could not be changed in the VPS. Finally I took another dedicated server running under Windows.

Comment: @HakunaN, try a `locate aio-max-nr` maybe it's in a different folder